# Migrate the custom spring boot starter which has its own entities and repositories from spring boot 2 to 3

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-boot-starter

I would like to migrate the custom spring boot starter which has its own entities and repositories from spring boot 2 to 3.

I currently have tried the following:

registar for entities:

```
public class StarterEntityRegistrar implements ImportBeanDefinitionRegistrar {

    @Override
    public void registerBeanDefinitions(AnnotationMetadata importingClassMetadata, BeanDefinitionRegistry registry) {
        AutoConfigurationPackages.register(registry, User.class.getPackage().getName());
    }
}
```

configuration class:

```
@Configuration
@AutoConfigureBefore(JpaRepositoriesAutoConfiguration.class)
@EnableJpaRepositories(basePackages = {"com.example.starter.repository"})
@Import(StarterEntityRegistrar.class)
public class UserManagementAutoConfiguration {
```

but unfortunately it doesn't work with spring boot 3, for spring boot 2 everything is ok.

When I start my spring boot app depending on this custom starter I can see
`Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Not a managed type: class com.example.starter.model.entity.User`

Do you have ideas how to fix it?

Comment: Hi, the issue seems here:
@EnableJpaRepositories(basePackages = {"com.example.starter.repository"})
it cannot find or load com.example.starter.model.entity.User
this file may be not with @entity or not in a folder already loaded

Comment: Unfortunately com.example.starter.model.entity.User has @Entity and it is in package

Comment: Have you [switched from `META-INF/spring.factories` to `META-INF/spring/org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.AutoConfiguration.imports`](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/wiki/Spring-Boot-3.0-Migration-Guide#auto-configuration-files) to register you auto-configuration classes?

Comment: @OleksiiPerets did you manage to to get this working.